# Fetching records from database in chunks

Tags: java, sql, rest, db2

My java web application is retrieving a large dataset from the DB (DB2) and displaying the records on a webpage. 
Since the number of records is very large , the page takes a little time to load (about 15 secs)
To improve this , I want to implement pagination on the server side , ie fetch only 50 records at a time and show it on the page. 
Then when the user clicks on Next , the next 50 records are fetched and displayed.

I have already implemented this on the client side ie I am showing the data in chunks of 50  , **but I am still fetching the entire data in one database call**, due to which the page takes time to load.

How can I implement the pagination on the server side ie fetch only 50 records at a time ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JDBC also has the concept of fetch size - Statement.setFetchsize and the fetchSize property of the driver.

Comment: @RobWilson JDBC fetch size is not what the OP wants. JDBC fetch size is a hint to the driver to fetch rows in batches of _(fetch size)_ rows, but it will still retrieve all rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. In your client code, keep track of the current offset that you want. In this case `LIMIT` would be 50 and `OFFSET` would be some multiple of 50.

`Select * From MY_TABLE ORDER BY XYZ LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0`